# Script for changing numbers giving error

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var adiInit = "xxxx",
        adiRVO = true;
    var adiFunc = null;
    (function () {
        var adiSrc = document.createElement("script");
        adiSrc.type = "text/javascript";
        adiSrc.async = true;
        adiSrc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://static-ssl" : "http://static-cdn") + ".responsetap.com/static/scripts/rTapTrack.min.js";
        var s = document.getElementById("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(adiSrc, s);
    })();
</script>
```

On add in footer variable s is coming null. so giving error in all browsers and phone numbers are not changing.

http://prntscr.com/a0k1vt

How can i resolve it . Please need fix asap

Comment: Why did you write all your code on one line? How do you debug that?

Comment: voting this up because of the informative link, also you can use http://jsbeautifier.org to beautify your js

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below instead of  `var s = document.getElementById("script")[0];`

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks VtZ, for such a great reply and quick answer. You are expert of JS

Comment: @dipanshu no problem